# Attach 'onpaste' Property to Element From JS Function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working in a framework that won't let me directly view or edit the tag of a particular element, but will let me add code to the end of the document containing that element.

I'm trying to write a javascript function that will let me add an 'onpaste' property to that element (to disable pasting): IE,

`<input text id="MyID" />`

would become

`<input text id="MyID" onpaste="return false;"/>`

after the function is run.

Because I cannot see the other properties on the element I don't want to replace all content within the tag, only to append to it. I do have the element ID, but once I pull a getElementByID, how do I append the onpaste property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`onpaste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste) event.

```
var input = document.getElementById('MyID');
input.onpaste = function () {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an `onpaste` property that you can assign an event listener to. You could also use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

`document.getElementById('MyID').onpaste = function() { return false; }`